# Programmatic Cubic Regression

Tags: regression

All,

Thanks in advance for your help. There're a lot of "low hanging fruit" problems at work I need to tackle as a tech-level employee. One of them is curve-fitting 6 data points to a cubic curve, and the other regression questions don't address it as well.

The specific application is calibration of pressure sensors. First, the system calibration curve is set to $f(x) = x$. Next, data points are collected from $0$ to $x$ on the $x$-axis where $x$ is applied pressure and the 6 points are spaced $6/x$ units of pressure apart (the $y$-axis is the current provided by the sensor at a given pressure $x$).

The question is, from a programming perspective, how do I get the coefficients $a, b, c, d$  of the curve $dx^3+cx^2+bx+a$ to which the data points are fitted? In other words, what is a simple generalization/algorithm or pseudo-code of the operation?

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Would a general linear algebra approach be helpful?  I'm not sure how it would be optimized to your particular setting

Comment: @TerrorTech: Can you provide two samples of data points?

Comment: Yes, very. If you're going to use a programmatic example, please do so generally in pseudocode without use of computer-centric abstractions like pointers.

Comment: @Amzoti: if for example the sensor is rated for 600 bar, then pressure(x-axis) would be applied at 0 Bar, 100 Bar, 200 Bar, 300 Bar, 400 Bar, 500 Bar, and 600 Bar. The current produced by the sensor at each of those measurements would be the y-component of each of those six points. The question is, how do I fit those to a cubic curve and that curve's coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Our goal is to find a function of the form $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ that gives us the least-squares approximation to a set of data points $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\dots,(x_n,y_n)\}$

Let $A$ be the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & {x_1}^2 & {x_1}^3\\
1 & x_2 & {x_2}^2 & {x_2}^3\\ 
\,& \vdots & \vdots & \, \\
1 & x_n & {x_n}^2 & {x_n}^3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $z$ be the matrix
$$
z = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and let $y$ be the matrix
$$
y = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then (assuming no two $x_i$ are the same), the best fit curve will correspond to the unique solution (for $z$) to the matrix equation
$$
A^T A\, z = A^Ty
$$
Where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$.  That is,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
\end{bmatrix}= (A^T A)^{-1}[A^T y]
$$
We could make this run a little faster by using the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix $A^T A$ (see link in the comment below) since for your particular problem, the matrix $A^T A$ will be positive definite, so long as we list the $x_i$ in increasing order.  Besides that, you can never go terribly wrong solving a 4 by 4 system with Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Wikipedia has some ideas here about how to start optimizing this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Computation

Comment: Here's an explanation of why the L-U (Cholesky) decomposition would be useful http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html (see page 41)

Comment: Would you need to code the matrix computations, or do you have access to some sort of matrix-computation library in whatever language you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If you tabulate your data in Excel and plot it, you can ask it to Add Trendline, select a degree 3 polynomial, and show trendline equation.  That is probably the least work to get to a solution.  I don't know how to read the coefficients off in machine-readable form.

Any numerical analysis text will have a whole section on this.  I like chapter 15 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).  Obsolete versions are free on line.  You have a linear least squares problem, as your equation depends linearly on the parameters (the coefficients of your cubic), even if non-linearly on $x$.